# Using Win32InputBox in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, inputbox

I'm using this InputBox code (using dialog templates) -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13330/Using-Dialog-Templates-to-create-an-InputBox-in-C

and if I first call MessageBox(..) function everything works fine, but without them the application hangs! (there must be some initializing code in it)!

In fact I don't need the MessageBox(), only want to use this InputBox -> how can I realize it?

My steps:

- included Win32InputBox.h/.cpp
- included header to my file
- added `CWin32InputBox::InputBox(_T("Input Dialog"), _T("Please enter password"), buf, 100, false, NULL);` (wchar_t buf[100] = {0};)

My code:

```
void ClassA::SomeFunction()
{
    // ...
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "TEST!", "TEST", MB_ICONINFORMATION); // with this ALL OK
    wchar_t buf[100] = {0};
    CWin32InputBox::InputBox(_T("Input Dialog"), _T("Please enter password"), buf, 100, false, NULL);
    // ...
}
```

if the application hangs it's this line in `CWin32InputBox::InputBoxEx(...)`

```
INT_PTR r = ::DialogBoxIndirectParam(param->hInstance, dlgTemplate, param->hwndOwner, (DLGPROC)DlgProc, (LPARAM)&inputbox);
```

Thx

Comment: Show your code, I see nothing about MessageBox in refered codeproject article.

Comment: Given the fact you have to sign-in to CP to download the source, why not simply post a message at the bottom of the article asking the author for a hand? Either that, or post sufficient code to let someone answer your question without going to more effort than you have. :shrugs: As always, we get the best help when we make it easy for people to help us.. Good-luck :)

Comment: @enhzflep I know, but the article is rather old and I don't understand why the InputBox is only functional if calling a MessageBox() before! It's very weird! Maybe someone have a hint for me?!

Comment: Show your code! Not only steps.

Comment: @Xearinox which code? It's only the CWin32InputBox::InputBox(...) call! (the code is available at given link) But I will edit my answer nevertheless!

Comment: I dont see any MessageBox. Also what hangs? Any errors? Do you try debug?

Comment: @Xearinox Added some code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by creating a dummy window just right before calling InputBox!

```
void ClassA::SomeFunction()
{
    // ...
    // create a dummy window
    HWND dummyHWND = ::CreateWindowA("STATIC","dummy",WS_VISIBLE,0,0,100,100,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    wchar_t buf[100] = {0};
    CWin32InputBox::InputBox(_T("Input Dialog"), _T("Please enter KeyCard password"), buf, 100, false, dummyHWND);
    // ...
}
```